# Question with incorrect tags and answers for those tags

Tags: discussion, tags, answers

[How can I convert ticks to a date format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489243/how-can-i-convert-ticks-to-a-date-format) is tagged with [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) [sql-server-2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2005) while the code provided in the question is SQL.

The accepted answer is also SQL, but the other answers are for C#. The answers are useful, as indicated by the upvotes, for people who accidentally arrive on the question because of the incorrect tags.

What can we do with these answers? Perhaps move them to a similar question that actually is for C#?